# Great expectations installation to AWS EMR

Tags: python, amazon-emr, great-expectations

I tried to use great expectations for data quality purpose

I am running my jobs in AWS EMR cluster and I am trying to launch great expectations job on AWS EMR as well

I have bootstrap script for installation dependencies on a cluster. It looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yes | sudo yum install python3-devel
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo python3 -m pip install cython

sudo python3 -m pip install boto3==1.26.37
sudo python3 -m pip install great-expectations==0.15.36
```

I saw that all dependencies was installed correctly based on log outputs, but then job started I got the following error

```
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.17.3
your numpy version is 1.16.5.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.17.3 to use this pandas version
```

I tried to uninstall numpy and install it manually via pip in bootstrap script like this but it didn't help

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall --yes numpy
```

I don't understand why it happens

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo python3 -m pip install numpy==1.17.3
```

Comment: I tried to do the following 
`sudo python3 -m pip uninstall --yes numpy
sudo python3 -m pip install numpy==1.23.5
sudo python3 -m pip install great-expectations==0.15.36`
It didn't affect somehow the final result

Answer (score 0):

Usage of EMR of newer version solved problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).